# Raphael.js barchart plot using built in two dimensional array fails

Tags: javascript, graphael

I am trying to draw a bar chart(Raphael.js) using a two dimensional array i created inside the program(which i need to..)instead of passing actual values but no output getting a blank screen. Guessing g.bar.js having trouble parsing the array and the g.bar.js i have is from g.raphael.com. I have also tried the g.bar.js from https://github.com/vezult/g.raphael/blob/8a2b7dc3f97dedf5196791fa9eaa8640350d161a/g.bar.js but i am not even able to compile this thing. Barchart call r.barchart(5, 10, 300, 220, data, {stacked: true, type: "round"}).hoverColumn(fin2, fout2); data is a two dimensional array Any one experienced, please get in touch. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of 2d-array do you pass? What a program does generate it? Pls explain in details how do you pass it into script? What do you mean saying "not even able to compile this thing"?

Comment: I am constructing a two dimensional javascript array from json objects thats being passed into the program. And, yes, when i try the alternate g.bar.js it throws me with some compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still confused of your "compilation errors" because JS is interpretable not compilable script language.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="g.raphael.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="g.bar.js"></script>
```

Linking scripts in this order will not raise any error even with alternated g.bar.js. I've tested it.

Comment: Have you included all 3 scripts mentioned in my answer?It looks like g.raphael.js not linked since the Raphael.g extension is undefined.

Comment: Note.. Using  g.bar.js from g.raphaeljs.com i was able to draw a chart by passing hard coded two dimensionaly arrays.. ie ---- data2 = [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10, 15, 20, 20, 20, 15, 20], [20, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55, 5, 20, 7, 10, 14, 17], [12, 20, 30], [14]],--- but if i use say data2[array[][]] or data2[[array[0]][array[1]]..] it fails.

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed that altered g.bar.js is incomplete script and it's not being executed after loading... There should not be differences between passing parameters as hardcoded arrays or via variable names. Just update the question with a little piece of your code with .barchart call.

Comment: data3 = [chart];
                or
  data3 = [chart[0], chart[1], chart[2]];
                var c = r.barchart(5, 10, 300, 220, data3, {stacked: true, type: "round"}).hoverColumn(fin2, fout2); i used both data3s

Comment: Looks fine. What is displayed on `alert(typeof chart)`?

Comment: if i send a 1d array it takes and draw the chart but not for the 2d.. alert shows the complete populated array for 2d.

Comment: `typeof chart === 'object'` - that's the answer: chart is not pure js-array but hash with no `.length` property. You should convert chart to array before passing to `.barchart`. Do it with e.g. `$.makeArray(chart)`

Comment: Sorry, check `alert(chart.constructor)` too.

Comment: chart itself is a two dimensional array i built inside the program and i can access, print all of array's elements anytime keep in mind that if chart is an 1d it works..also just ran jQuery.makeArray and its still the same